# alternative to deprecated import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize.Inclusion;

Tags: xml, spring-boot, jackson

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize.Inclusion;

What is the alternative?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the *JavaDoc*:

> This property has been replaced by special-purpose  [@JsonInclude](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) annotation, introduced in Jackson 2.0.